# Regular expressions in Javascript with limiting amount of numbers/letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write regular expressions in javascript i need to have a three letter group of either ACF, ABQ, or BXD the character after must be hyphen followed by either 6 or 9 then 5 numbers between 0-9

This is my attempt i'm not sure where I am going wrong?

```
/ACF|ABQ|BXD-^6|9[0-9]{5}
```

Comment: Did you check what that regex actually _means_? See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/Vz6OuY/1.

Comment: That ^ in the regex is a special character that means "beginning of line."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the first 3 alternations in a non capture group, and you should put the `^` at the start of the pattern.

If you want to match 6 or 9 you can use a character class `[69]`

The `$` at the end denotes the end of the string.

The pattern can be written as:

```
^(?:ACF|ABQ|BXD)-[69][0-9]{5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U98dQq/1)